# Having Trouble Shredding XML to SQL Table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

Using SQL Server 2008, I need to select this XML into a Table.   I can't get it to return each row.

```
Declare @CurrentStatusInfoList xml
Set @CurrentStatusInfoList = '<CurrentStatusInfoList>
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="568" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000058170" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="615" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000059580" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1199" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000066117" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="997" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000063447" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1208" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000066265" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1577" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000069853" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
</CurrentStatusInfoList>'

 DECLARE @StatusTable 
    TABLE(           
             eFolderID varchar(100),
             ItemID bigint,
             eStageName varchar(100),
             Caption varchar(100)
         )

 INSERT INTO              
  @StatusTable (eFolderID, ItemID,eStageName,Caption)              
 SELECT               
  @CurrentStatusInfoList.value('(//@eFolderID)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as eFolderID,
  @CurrentStatusInfoList.value('(//@ItemID)[1]', 'bigint') as ItemID,
  @CurrentStatusInfoList.value('(//@eStageName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as eStageName, 
  @CurrentStatusInfoList.value('(//@Caption)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Caption 
FROM @CurrentStatusInfoList.nodes('//CurrentStatusInfoList/CurrentStatusInfo') 
    AS ParamValues(eFolderID)                 

 Select * from @StatusTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @CurrentStatusInfoList xml
Set @CurrentStatusInfoList = '<CurrentStatusInfoList>
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="568" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000058170" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="615" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000059580" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1199" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000066117" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="997" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000063447" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1208" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000066265" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
  <CurrentStatusInfo Caption="Route" ItemID="1577" eFolderID="0900000000000000000000000069853" eStageName="ustg_Route" /> 
</CurrentStatusInfoList>'

 DECLARE @StatusTable 
    TABLE(           
             eFolderID varchar(100),
             ItemID bigint,
             eStageName varchar(100),
             Caption varchar(100)
         )

 INSERT INTO              
  @StatusTable (eFolderID, ItemID,eStageName,Caption)              
 SELECT               
  CurrentStatusInfo.value('@eFolderID', 'varchar(100)') as eFolderID,
  CurrentStatusInfo.value('@ItemID', 'bigint') as ItemID,
  CurrentStatusInfo.value('@eStageName', 'varchar(100)') as eStageName, 
  CurrentStatusInfo.value('@Caption', 'varchar(100)') as Caption 
FROM @CurrentStatusInfoList.nodes('//CurrentStatusInfoList/CurrentStatusInfo') as CurrentStatusInfoList(CurrentStatusInfo)

 Select * from @StatusTable
```

Comment: +1. Attributes have only one value so `(@eFolderId)[1]` can be expressed more directly as `@eFolderID`

Comment: as CurrentStatusInfoList(CurrentStatusInfo) is what I was missing, and do not completely understand.  Can you explain or link me to something that explains the concept?

Comment: CurrentStatusInfoList(CurrentStatusInfo) is a two part Alias. The CurrentStatusInfoList is the table containing the resulting row set from the XPath query (nodes('//...')) and CurrentStatusInfo is the column name within that table containing the XML for each item selected. Find more info here: [nodes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: hmph... I thought nodes just referred to an XML node.  Learn something new everyday.  +1 @jdavies